# Facebook written by author name

Tags: html, facebook, blogs, meta

I'm trying to add author names to links when they are shared on Facebook statuses. I see that some pages, when shared, get a additional string of text next to the domain in the bottom of the box, where the author's name is placed. For example, when I share this link:

https://www.ted.com/talks/chris_hadfield_what_i_learned_from_going_blind_in_space#t-4690

I see "ted.com | By Chris Hadfield" in the preview box.

How is this done?

Comment: I would guess using article:author as specified http://ogp.me/ . But looking at the site they do `<meta content="Chris Hadfield" name="author" />` so I guess that works too

Comment: @WizKid That link did alert me to how I should be supplying basic Open Graph meta, but neither name="author" nor property:"article:author" seem to be the key here.

Comment: You used https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to check if you get any errors and to recache?